# Porblem Publishing Sonar and IR Data

Tags: ros, sonar, sensor, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Not sure what's the matter here. If I use rostopic list, when my publisher has advertises Sonar messages I see /Sonar in the list. However if I try just the IR data it sometimes works most of the time not. The ad code is simply:

```
    // Sonar Range Test
    /*  bool publish_sonar = true;
n.param("publish_sonar", publish_sonar, publish_sonar);
ros::Publisher sonar_pub;

if(publish_sonar) 
{
    sonar_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("Sonar", 1000);
}

    */  // IR Range Test
bool publish_ir = true;
n.param("publish_ir", publish_ir, publish_ir);
ros::Publisher ir_pub;

if(ir_pub) 
{
    ir_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("InfraRed", 1000);
}
```

Any suggestions would me v welcome - I want my node to publish both at the end of the day. The TF for both works fine.

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39400/porblem-publishing-sonar-and-ir-data/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably want your IR if statement to be:

```
if(publish_ir)
```

not

```
if(ir_pub)
```

I would expect doing `if(ros::Publisher)` before it has been created using e.g. `n.advertise` to return false.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-07-22**:
yes that was it. Thanks Eric